# Recommendation on something like drag and drop library for angular 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I want to create something like below:

[image]

Whereby I have a button "Add another item" which i can create multiple drag and drops. And I can rearrange each div by dragging it as well as a remove button for me to remove the div. Any libraries you guys recommend to do so in angular 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[drag n drop](https://github.com/akserg/ng2-dnd)** library with angular4 , which provides exactly what you need.

```
import {DndModule} from 'ng2-dnd';
```

Answer (score 2):

ngx-dnd one is a good one https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-dnd
And here is a demo https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-dnd/

```
npm i @swimlane/ngx-dnd --save
```

Then add `NgxDnDModule` to your application module